# Probability of at most $K$ consecutive zeroes in a sequence of 0s and 1s

Tags: pr.probability

I want to prove that in a sequence W of length n, consisting of 1s and 0s,  $P$( in $W$ there is at most $\frac{\log_2n}2$ consecutive zeroes )  $\leq \frac{K}{n} $ for some constant K. Can anyone help me start on the problem or refer me to some literature that could be of help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you expect this result to be true? and on a related note, where/how does the problem originate?

Comment: Ah, probably I made a wrong edit. In any case, please specify the base of logarithm.

Comment: Do you mean that the entries of your sequence are independent, and the 0's and 1's are equiprobable (i.e., 0 w/p 1/2, 1 w/p 1/2)?

Comment: The sequence is randomly chosen between all possible combinations of sequences of length n of 1s and 0s.

Comment: The title asks a different question than the question in the body.

Comment: @user1946334 - then what you want to prove is probably wrong, because the "typical" longest sequence of 0's should be of length roughly $\log_2 n$. Anyhow, see the links below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<1<b$. I prove that for large $n$:

1) the probability that a random sequence of length $n$ has at least $B:=b\log_2 n$ consecutive zeroes is at most $n^{1-b}$;

2) the probability that a random sequence of length $n$ does not contain $A:=\lfloor a\log_2 n\rfloor$ consecutive zeroes is at most $e^{-n^{1-a+o(1)}}=O(n^{-M})$ for any $M>0$.

Proofs. 1) For each possible place of $\lceil B\rceil $ consecutive positions consider the event: all positions are 0. Denote these events $E_1,E_2,\dots$. The sum of their probabilities does not exceed
$$\frac{n}{2^B}\leqslant n^{1-b}.
$$

2) Choose $m:=\lfloor n/A\rfloor$ disjoint segments of $A$ consecutive places. The probability that none of them contains only zeroes equals
$$
(1-2^{-A})^m\leqslant e^{-m\cdot 2^{-A}}=e^{-n^{1-a+o(1)}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the longest run of 0's in the i.i.d. setting, see this paper:   [http://gato-docs.its.txstate.edu%2Fmathworks%2FDistributionOfLongestRun.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE8shEgVJmaWNEVSYv5YNRIs088CA&sig2=OTB5H3mF7NVoEwIZs_foJw](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjPoKa9i-7KAhUGrB4KHZFtAEUQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgato-docs.its.txstate.edu%2Fmathworks%2FDistributionOfLongestRun.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE8shEgVJmaWNEVSYv5YNRIs088CA&sig2=OTB5H3mF7NVoEwIZs_foJw)

Also this:
L. Gordon, M.F. Schilling, M.S. Waterman (1986)
An extreme value theory for long head runs. 
*Probab. Theory Relat. Fields* **72**, 279-287.